# How can sbt pull dependency artifacts from git?

Tags: git, scala, build, sbt, build-dependencies

I've heard (and I know I've seen examples too, if only I can remember where) that `sbt` can obtain dependencies from a git repo.

I am looking to obtain the dependency [harrah/up](https://github.com/harrah/up) from github. The repository does not provide any artifact JAR files, only a source tree which is set up to be built using `sbt`. The process that I am imagining is that `sbt` will download the source repo, build it, and then use that as the dependency artifact.

I may be imagining that `sbt` can in fact do something like this. Can it? And if so, how?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Yes indeed. You can give your `Project` a dependency with the `dependsOn` operator, and you can reference a Github project by its URI, for example `RootProject(uri("git://github.com/dragos/dupcheck.git"))`. Alternatively, you can `git clone` the project, and then reference your local copy with `RootProject(file(...))`. See ["Full Configuration"](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Full-Configuration) on the SBT wiki for details and examples.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to include this in `build.sbt`?

Comment: @Owen, I'm not sure, but I suspect not. Doesn't `build.sbt` need to contain newline separated `Setting`s? Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes; that's correct (though I didn't know what when I asked). So the question reduces to whether there is a `Setting` for that -- it's possible that `projectDependencies` is such a setting; I'm not sure.

Comment: You do need a .scala build for this.

Comment: Great insight. But if that project changes, how do you force `sbt` to recompile it? `clean` does not seem to help.

Comment: Hi Axel22, did you find any solution to your problem?

Comment: How can you configure this in situations where the git repo is private? Is there a way to configure SBT to send a deploy key, which could be set in a dotfile or environment variable?

Comment: I'd also like to know how to make sbt pull changes after pushing new commit to the github repository, if I point it to `#master`, reload, it clones it, then I push new commit to master and sbt still works with the originally cloned repository without noticing a new commit. At this point one have to either delete it from `/.sbt/0.13/staging/` and have sbt clone it again or going there and doing `git pull`

Answer (score 106):

You can import unpackaged dependencies into your project from GitHub by treating them as project dependencies, using the `dependsOn` operator. (This is distinct from the way that precompiled library dependencies are included).

Note that you can specify which branch to pull using `#` notation. Here's some Scala SBT code that is working well for me:

```
object V {
  val depProject = "master"
  // Other library versions
}

object Projects {
  lazy val depProject = RootProject(uri("git://github.com/me/dep-project.git#%s".format(V.depProject)))
}

// Library dependencies
lazy val myProject = Project("my-project", file("."))
.settings(myProjectSettings: _*)
.dependsOn(Projects.depProject)
.settings(
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(...
```

Note that if you have multiple SBT projects dependending on the same external project, it's worth setting up a central `sbt.boot.directory` to avoid unnecessary recompilations (see [instructions here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/35)).

Comment: can sbt also keep the local git updated with "git pull"? Or do I need to do that manually?

Comment: Is it possible to set `"my-project"` dynamically, using the `name := "MyProject"` setting from `build.sbt` in project root?

Comment: `git://` protocol syntax doesn't seem to work for me in play/sbt 13.0. `https://` works though. This might also be caused by a git specific setting.

Comment: Using sbt 0.13.9 and sbt updates the git dependency correctly using a shallow clone (git clone --depth 1).

Comment: The branch only works if set to `master`, otherwise I get: `[error] No project 'project_name' in 'ssh://git@github.com/user/project.git#branch'`

Comment: @Neil you've referenced the subproject as `project_name` in your top level project but in the subproject `build.sbt` you've likely referenced it as something else. The `val` name determines the project name.

Answer (score 10):

Since I had problems getting the dependencies of my library resolved (using the suggested `RootProject`) I'd like to point out to the object called `ProjectRef`. Thus, if one need to depend on a library residing in git, I suggest to do so as follows:

```
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._

object MyBuild extends Build {

  lazy val root = Project("root", file("."))
    .dependsOn(myLibraryinGit)
    .settings(
      ...,
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(...))

  lazy val myLibraryinGit = ProjectRef(uri("git://git@github.com:user/repo.git#branch"), "repo-name")

}
```

*Source: http://blog.xebia.com/git-subproject-compile-time-dependencies-in-sbt/*

Comment: In case of git clone error try with `https uri` version.

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to add an answer for sbt 0.13+. Just put something like this to your `build.sbt` on project root folder (not `Build.scala`):

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).dependsOn(playJongo)

lazy val playJongo = RootProject(uri("https://github.com/bekce/play-jongo.git"))
```