# How do I refresh updated Git dependency artifacts in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

I've configured SBT (0.11.0) to pull in a GitHub project as a dependency, as per my answer on [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550376/how-can-sbt-pull-dependency-artifacts-from-git/8828803#8828803).

It works fine except that I can't seem to get SBT to re-compile my Git dependency when it gets updated. In other words: if I make an update to the dependency, push to Git and reload my project's SBT and run `package`, then SBT does not recompile the external Git dependency when compiling my project.

I've tried creating a new branch in my Git dependency (say, `forcenew`) and updating the branch in my SBT project configuration to use this:

```
lazy val depProject = RootProject(uri("git://github.com/me/dep-project.git#forcenew"))
```

But even this doesn't force a refresh. I'm a bit stumped - I can't even find where SBT puts the Git project to compile it (it doesn't seem to be in `~/.sbt/` or `~/.ivy2/`)...

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: compiled github project exists in `~/.sbt/staging/` ?

Comment: I had similar trouble with `-SNAPSHOT` Ivy dependencies, which were only re-resolved after running a `clean` in sbt.  Does `clean` solve this for git dependencies too?

Comment: Thanks James, Kenji. `clean` doesn't seem to work - `rm -rf ~/.sbt/staging/` does the job, but is obviously the nuclear option...

Comment: I opened an issue for this: https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/issues/335

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<s>From: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/335</s>

this should be fixed in 0.12.0, just call "sbt update"

It was fixed in 0.12.0 so `sbt update` is enough, [but got back in 13.0](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1284) -- for now, you have to wipe dependency from `~/.sbt/staging/` manually

Answer (score 10):

You likely want to clear out `~/.sbt/staging/`

Comment: any reason why it's not automatic ?

Comment: I think Intellij takes care if the issue if you enable auto-import when you create the project... not sure tho

Answer (score 4):

A quick hack you can add to your build.sbt:

```
def removegit = Command.command("removegit"){state =>
  val home = sys.env("HOME")
  val k = ("rm -rf "+ home + "/.sbt/0.13/staging/").!
  state
}

commands ++= Seq(removegit)
```

And then `sbt removegit` will wipe that directory. This doesn't do anything smart like checking commits, which would be a great upgrade...  The repos are being stored in `~/.sbt/0.13/staging/` on my machine, you may need to adjust that.