# How to get an unpackaged SBT dependency included in a Proguard jar?

Tags: sbt, proguard

I've configured SBT (0.11.0) to pull in a GitHub project as a dependency, as per my answer on [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550376/how-can-sbt-pull-dependency-artifacts-from-git/8828803#8828803).

It works fine except that I can't seem to get Proguard to include those unpackaged dependencies when creating its standalone jar. (I'm using the excellent [xsbt-proguard-plugin](https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-proguard-plugin).)

I've tried manually "keeping" the project's class files with an argument like this:

```
"-keep class com.my.unpackageddependency.*"
```

But this doesn't work... Any help greatly appreciated!