# How do I tell sbt to use a nightly build of Scala 2.10?

Tags: scala, sbt

Scala Migrations, which builds with sbt, found [SI-6646](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6646) in Scala 2.10.0-RC2.  I want to test the committed fix before RC3 is released to confirm it all works.  How do I tell sbt to use a nightly Scala 2.10.0 build?

Comment: For Scala 2.12, 2.13, and 3, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622878/how-do-i-use-a-nightly-build-of-scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to add a new resolver to your project settings in your `.build`. We import the Sonatype repository which have the last commits from Scala. Look at [this link](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/scala-lang/) to see the list of all the versions available.

```
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")
```

Then just change the Scala version, again in the sbt settings.

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but you could pull the code from github (https://github.com/scala/scala) by following this question:
[How can sbt pull dependency artifacts from git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550376/how-can-sbt-pull-dependency-artifacts-from-git)

Then, call ant from sbt to build the compiler:
https://bitbucket.org/jmhofer/ant4sbt/wiki/Home

The only part I am not certain about is that you need to copy the scala compiler and libraries in the correct folder that sbt uses, but you can look at where that goes on your machine.

Then, just do a clean and build.

Comment: I think the scala compile is a pretty big one, I would rather just pull the SNAPSHOT jars.