# How to add dependencies in Eclipse which sbt and Play 2.0 can see

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am working on a Scala library in Eclipse (proj1).

This library I would like to test in a Play 2.0 Scala web app.
So I have run the eclipse command from the cmd line and imported the project into Eclipse (proj2).

So I have two eclipse projects side by side. I can add the first project (proj1) to the build path of proj2 in Eclipse.
This way I can import the library and write the code.

But when Play compiles it can't see library I've added to the build path.
If I run the eclipse command again the library is removed from the build path.

Is there any way to reference the project? I would prefer not to build a jar and import that via sbt.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550376/how-can-sbt-pull-dependency-artifacts-from-git answers it

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at that

Comment: What I was trying was to use linked resources. Just found out that it is not supported in sbt yet. I will try Ivan's approach instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simply add them via sbt and regenerate the eclipse project from the Play console.

Comment: Can you give an example of your build file where you have added an eclipse project? That would be very helpful thanks.

Comment: I ended up creating a sbt project for the library and added it to my play app as done in this config file - https://github.com/un-jon/play2MultiModule/blob/master/playapp/project/Build.scala