# SBT dependsOn RootProject: doesn't compile the dependency

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, banana-rdf

I have a pretty simple configuration:

```
  //lazy val bananaRdfProject = RootProject( uri("git://github.com:stample/banana-rdf.git#"+bananaGitBranch) )
  // lazy val bananaRdfProject = RootProject( uri("https://github.com/stample/banana-rdf.git#"+bananaGitBranch) )
  // lazy val bananaRdfProject = ProjectRef( uri("https://github.com/stample/banana-rdf.git#"+bananaGitBranch) ,"banana-rdf")
  lazy val bananaRdfProject = RootProject( file("../banana-rdf") )


  lazy val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(...)
                     .dependsOn( bananaRdfProject )
```

I tried using the 4 different project declarations above for bananaRdfProject.

As I may edit this banana-rdf locally, I want it to be recompiled each time I build my play project, so that I do not have to publish the banana-rdf...

But when I try to compile my main play project, that uses banana-rdf, it doesn't compile banana-rdf, but tries to compile the main project: the compilation fails because banana-rdf classes are missing in the classpath.

```
sebastien@clemence-XPS-L412Z:rww-play (master *%)$ ./play.old/play
[info] Loading project definition from /home/sebastien/Bureau/rww-play/project
[warn] there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
[warn] one warning found
[info] Loading project definition from /home/sebastien/Bureau/banana-rdf/project
[info] Updating {file:/home/sebastien/Bureau/banana-rdf/project/}banana-rdf-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to /home/sebastien/Bureau/banana-rdf/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
[warn] there were 11 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
[warn] there were 2 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
[warn] two warnings found
[info] Set current project to RWWeb (in build file:/home/sebastien/Bureau/rww-play/)
       _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |
|  __/|_|\____|\__ /
|_|            |__/

play 2.2-TLS built with Scala 2.10.3-RC3 (running Java 1.7.0_45), http://www.playframework.com

> Type "help play" or "license" for more information.
> Type "exit" or use Ctrl+D to leave this console.

[RWWeb] $ compile
[info] Updating {file:/home/sebastien/Bureau/banana-rdf/}banana...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/home/sebastien/Bureau/rww-play/}RWWeb...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 53 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /home/sebastien/Bureau/rww-play/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /home/sebastien/Bureau/rww-play/app/controllers/CORSProxy.scala:4: object banana is not a member of package org.w3
[error] import org.w3.banana.plantain.Plantain
[error]               ^
[error] /home/sebastien/Bureau/rww-play/app/controllers/CORSProxy.scala:7: not found: type Plantain
[error] object CORSProxy extends org.www.readwriteweb.play.CORSProxy[Plantain](webClient) 
.................
```

Isn't it supposed to compile banana-rdf before trying to compile my main project? If not, what is the point of depending on an external RootProject?

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/q/20083564/1305344

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `RootProject(file("../banana-rdf"))` project reference just references the root project, and what you really need is a reference to the `banana-rdf` subproject (in the `rdf` subdirectory).

The available subprojects are defined in https://github.com/w3c/banana-rdf/blob/master/project/build.scala. There are a few:

```
[main]> projects
[info] In file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/19832655/
[info]   * main
[info] In https://github.com/w3c/banana-rdf.git
[info]     banana
[info]     banana-jena
[info]     banana-rdf
[info]     banana-rdf-test-suite
[info]     banana-sesame
[info]     examples
[info]     experimental
[info]     ldp
[info]     patch
```

To reference `banana-rdf` you should then use the following `ProjectRef` pointing at a right module (subproject) in a build configuration. Note `ProjectRef` as well as the name of the subproject - `banana-rdf`.

```
lazy val bananaRdfProject =
  ProjectRef(uri("https://github.com/w3c/banana-rdf.git"), "banana-rdf")
```

With the `ProjectRef` you should be able to resolve any types defined in the `banana-rdf` subproject.

Comment: What's the difference between RootProject and ProjectRef? Are their intended purposes documented anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between aggregate projects and dependsOn. I think you need to aggregate to get all projects to build together, dependsOn only makes sure the classes from that project is on the classpath, but it could of course be an old artifact if you haven't built it recently. Check out the sbt docs for more info: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html