# Can build.sbt in Play 2.2+ project dependsOn a GitHub project SBT?

Tags: git, heroku, playframework-2.0, sbt

Is it possible to write a `build.sbt` for Play **2.2+** that `dependsOn` a GitHub project? The dependency is a library, not a Play module, and it is a private BitBucket repo so it needs authentication. The resulting project is pushed up to Heroku for deployment.

[How can sbt pull dependency artifacts from git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550376/how-can-sbt-pull-dependency-artifacts-from-git/7550450#7550450) doesn't show the `build.sbt` syntax and doesn't address the authentication issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite legitimate and the answer is as simple as the following in `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val bananaRdfProject =
  ProjectRef(uri("https://github.com/w3c/banana-rdf.git"), "banana-rdf")
```

and then `dependsOn` the `lazy val`, or

```
lazy val core = project dependsOn(
  ProjectRef(uri("git://github.com/w3c/banana-rdf.git"), "banana-jena")
)
```

See [Can multi-projects from GIT be used as SBT dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20083564/1305344) and [SBT dependsOn RootProject: doesn't compile the dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19832655/1305344).

Comment: How would authentication be specified for a private BitBucket project?

Comment: I didn't try it out, but **if** there's a hg URL that accepts username and password, that would do the trick. Since SBT uses `hg` command line tool, the tool can handle it with a special configuration - see [How to save username and password with Mercurial?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2589195/1305344).

Comment: My question is about git.

Comment: I think the combination of `git clone` (authentication) and `RootProject` (referencing the cloned project) might be a good fit to your use case.

Comment: Sounds nice. How exactly would that work for Heroku?

Comment: I would expect Heroku scripts to allow to perform actions, e.g. `git clone` before others. I don't know the details, though.

Comment: Heroku is driven from git push. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code

Comment: That's correct, but you can write scripts as part of a build/deployment process.

Comment: Of course. The question is how to supply authentication information

Comment: I tried this in my build.sbt file, and I see SBT cloning the dependency, placing it in ~/.sbt and even in IntellJ, it shows up now as a module, but I still can't import any class files from that module, either in IntellJ or if I give sbt a compile command