# How to declare subproject dependency from another project?

Tags: sbt

I have two projects `A` and `B` in sibling directories. I know I can make `A` depend on `B` using `RootProject`:

```
object A extends Build {
  lazy val A = project in file(".") dependsOn(B)
  lazy val B = RootProject(file("../B"))
}
```

But `B` includes two `core` and `extensions` subprojects, and I want to depend on `core` only. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turns out to be given at [SBT dependsOn RootProject: doesn't compile the dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19832655/1305344):

```
lazy val BCore = ProjectRef(file("../B"), "core")
```