# sbt-unidoc -- how to exclude a sub-module from a RootProject

Tags: scala, sbt

I am building compound API docs using the [sbt-unidoc](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-unidoc) plugin. I am linking to various projects on GitHub using sbt's `RootProject` constructor with URIs.

One of these projects has mutually exclusive sub-projects:

```
val foo = RootProject(uri("git://github.com/Foo/Bar.git#v1.0.0"))
```

That is, in this project foo, there are two sub-modules `foo-db1` and `foo-db2`, which contain the same types but are built against different dependency library versions.

Now when I try to run `unidoc`, it fails because a type is defined twice from unidoc's perspective. From the documentation, I can see there is a filter function:

```
unidocProjectFilter in (ScalaUnidoc, unidoc) := inAnyProject -- inProjects(app)
```

But **how do I create an identifier for a sub-module from my `RootProject`**?
In other words, how would I do this:

```
unidocProjectFilter in (ScalaUnidoc, unidoc) := inAnyProject --
  inProjects(foo).SELECT_SUB_PROJECT(foo-v1)
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is found in [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832655/sbt-dependson-rootproject-doesnt-compile-the-dependency): Instead of using `RootProject`, one creates a number of `ProjectRef` instances.

```
import UnidocKeys._

val fooURI = uri("git://github.com/Foo/Bar.git#v1.0.0")
val fooDb1 = ProjectRef(fooURI, "foo-db1") // sub-module I don't want
val fooDb2 = ProjectRef(fooURI, "foo-db2") // sub-module I want

val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings( ... )
  .settings(unidocSettings: _*)
  .settings(site.settings ++ ghpages.settings: _*)
  .settings(
    unidocProjectFilter in (ScalaUnidoc, unidoc) := 
      inAnyProject -- inProjects(fooDb1)
  )
  .aggregate(fooDb2)
```

Note that putting only `fooDb2` in the aggregate and leaving `fooDb1` out, does not have any effect. It seems that unidoc always includes all sub-modules, no matter, so one has to use the `unidocProjectFilter` to explicitly remove projects, even if they don't appear in the aggregate.