# Can multi-projects from GIT be used as SBT dependencies?

Tags: scala, sbt, banana-rdf

I would like to use [banana-rdf](https://github.com/w3c/banana-rdf) in my project, ideally by defining it as a dependency in a `build.scala` using `dependsOn`:

```
lazy val root = Project("root", file(".")) dependsOn RootProject(uri("git://github.com/w3c/banana-rdf"))
```

However, banana-rdf is a [multi-project so needs to be composed differently](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html). From what I can see, these multi-project definitions only allow you to specify project locations as file paths, and won't allow URIs.

**Question:** Am I right in saying that I have to clone these multi-project GIT dependencies into my project and reference them as folders?

I rather like the idea of leaving all the GIT cloning up to SBT, and having these cloned in some tmp SBT folder rather than cluttering up my project...

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/q/19832655/1305344

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I depend on  Banana RDF subprojects all the time with `ProjectRef`, like this:

```
lazy val core: Project = Project(
  ...
).dependsOn(
  ProjectRef(uri("git://github.com/w3c/banana-rdf.git"), "banana-jena")
)
```

One especially nice part is that you can just tack a commit or branch name as a fragment identifier on the URI and everything works exactly as you'd expect.

Comment: I tried this and it works well, however when I update the dependency, my main project doesn't seem to see the change. What did you do to keep things in sync?

Comment: sbt 0.13.13 does not seem to support cross-compiling for this: the received dependency is for the default Scala version. I'm looking for a way out for this..