# Using Git local repository as dependency in SBT project?

Tags: git, scala, sbt

I cloned a repository from GitHub to my local machine, changed it to fit my needs and now I'm going to use it in my project. I guess I must use `.jar` file from it. However, there is no such a file.

Do I have to generate it myself?

Also, how do I refer to it? I don't want to copy it to `/lib` folder for now because I keep working on the cloned project. As I found out I have to use this:

```
resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"
```

However, I don't have the file `build.sbt`, I only have file a plain scala file titled `Build.scala` and it's not possible to use code above in it.

Also, it says `/.m2/repository`, but how does it know where `.jar` file is in this repository?

Comment: SBT uses a local ivy cache repository and follows a maven based project structure. Look in `~/.ivy2/cache` for built jars. You may also want to look at [fetching dependencies from git](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7550376/205936)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/20083564/1305344 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/7550376/1305344

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, it is not because those question are not about a local dependency.

Answer (score 4):

Since the project comes from GitHub I assume it's a git project. The solution is to use `RootProject` with git URI as a reference to your cloned git project.

Say you cloned the project to `/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-git/git-repo` (as I did in [Can SBT refresh git uri dependency (always or on demand)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21211671/1305344)).

Do `git log` to find out the last commit you want to reference and use it in the git URI of the referenced project in SBT - in `dependsOn`.

Given the last commit is `a221379c7f82e5cc089cbf9347d473ef58255bb2`, `build.sbt` could look as follows:

```
lazy val v = "a221379c7f82e5cc089cbf9347d473ef58255bb2"

lazy val g = RootProject(uri(s"git:file:///Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-git/git-repo/#$v"))

lazy val root = project in file(".") dependsOn g
```

It's also possible to leave out the commit id and keep up with the development in the referenced git project after it's updated with `git fetch` followed by `git merge` as described in [git-pull(1) Manual Page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull.html).

Comment: I applied your solution, it compiles but I finally get a ClassNotFoundException. Any idea why?

Comment: What kind of project is this - maven, gradle, sbt? Does the project follow standard directory structure of Maven/sbt? As a matter of fact, even with a proper setup of the projects you may face CNFE due to a bug in the project(s). Would you mind sharing the project via github?