# How to depend on Maven-managed project on GitHub?

Tags: git, maven, github, sbt

My project has a dependency on a library that is available on GitHub, but with no binaries available. How can I tell sbt that I depend on it, so that it pulls the code and compiles it, but keeps it separate from mine? If need be, I can pull it manually - my main goal is a) to keep it clean and b) to transitively depend on all its maven dependencies.

UPDATE: The project that I'm depending on is built with Maven.

Comment: Is the project you are depending on built with SBT?

Comment: @lpiepiora No, it's Maven

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that there's no easy way to do what you're after - to have sbt download the project (possible - see below), `mvn` it (doable with some development) and depend on it (feature available out of the box).

If it were a sbt build, it'd be possible with ease. You can check the following questions to build a solution for you:

- [How can sbt pull dependency artifacts from git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7550376/1305344)
- [Can SBT refresh git uri dependency (always or on demand)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21174681/1305344)
- [Can multi-projects from GIT be used as SBT dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20083564/1305344)

BTW, thinking aloud - you could also build a ModuleId you depend on that would execute `git fetch`, execute `mvn` and offer the result as a ModuleId/ProjectRef. It could be possible.

> If need be, I can pull it manually - my main goal is a) to keep it
>   clean and b) to transitively depend on all its maven dependencies.

What about `mvn install` to the local Maven repo and add `Resolver.mavenLocal` to `resolvers` in the dependent projects? It should make it fine.