# How to use an SBT plugin in the plugin's own project?

Tags: sbt

I'm making first steps with an SBT plugin.

```
object WoahPlugin extends Plugin {
  override lazy val settings = commands += thingCommand

  lazy val thingCommand = Command.command("thing") {state: State =>
    println("this is the thing~!")
    state
  }
}
```

After defining a command, I want to try it out. Do I need to build the plugin and define a new project that uses it in order to try it out? Or can I open an SBT session in the plugin's project and import it directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** You can't have a plugin project and be able to test it out without another project that uses it.

A plugin enhances a build definition of a project so you set up a plugin that expands the project with capabilities you want - additional settings and tasks. See [Plugins](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Plugins.html) in the official documentation of sbt.

You set up plugins in meta-project under `project` directory, by convention usually in `project/plugins.sbt` (but any `project/*.sbt` file would do).

If you need to test a plugin you've got two notable choices that all boil down to having a separate project for the plugin and another to use it - the choice is about the place where the test project is as compared to the plugin project under test.

### Plugin project in `project` metaproject

You can have the sources of the plugin under `project/src/main/scala` so they belong to their own project, but because of the directory they live in `project`, they automatically become part of the metaproject for another project one level up.

With the plugin's sources inside the meta-project `project` you can define a plugin dependency in `project/plugins.sbt` and have the plugin installed ([given the recent changes to sbt since 0.13.5](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Using-Plugins.html#Enabling+and+disabling+auto+plugins) it doesn't necessarily mean the plugin's enabled).

### Plugin project anywhere

The plugin project is a sbt project and as such can be referenced from another sbt project using `ProjectRef`. If it's a `git://` or `file://` project, you declare the dependency on the plugin project using `dependsOn` and the project reference with `ProjectRef`.

See [Can multi-projects from GIT be used as SBT dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20083564/1305344) and [How can sbt pull dependency artifacts from git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7550376/1305344).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. Your edit of the title is odd though. I was asking if it is possible, and the answer is no. Now it looks as though I've made an assumption that it is possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for accepting the answer. As to the title's change I think it doesn't make that much difference however I'm later going to correct it unless you beat me to it.