# Publish local but into a project itself

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

I have a dependency in a scala project which I want to include in it so that it will be available in the project without having to use the Internet for everyone who uses the project. In other words, I want to do kind of "publish local" but a little differently: publish local publishes it locally only at my machine and everyone using the project will have to publish it locally on their machine as well, whereas I want to publish this dependency directly in this scala project.

Is it possible and how?

**UPDATE**:

I want to give the project to a person over the Internet. I want they to download only my project without having to download anything else. But my project has one external dependency which I can download myself.

Can I include this dependency (after downloading it myself) into the project and give the project to the person so they'll be able to run it successfully? And how? And how do I make sbt to load it from the project and not from the Internet or anywhere else?

Comment: Does [Unmanaged Dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html#unmanaged-dependencies) look like what you want? You can just add your dependency into a `lib` folder in your project and bundle it for others to use. You may also want to look at [Multi-project  builds](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html) for projects with multiple modules.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You don't want to publish it to the internet, but you don't want to publish it locally, either. What other choices could there possibly be...? I don't know what "publish this dependency directly" means.

Comment: @SethTisue  **You don't want to publish it to the internet** -- not true.

Comment: Fine, but I'm still left guessing what your actual requirements are. Maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550376/how-can-sbt-pull-dependency-artifacts-from-git

Comment: @S.R.I, I have a big project containing some small ones. In what lib directory do I have to put a .jar file (in the root of the main project or in the root of some subproject)?

Comment: @SethTisue, the link you provided is not really what I am looking for because describes how to publish it locally, meaning not in the project but in the home directory of the user.

Comment: @Alex What? No, I think you are mistaken; the process described in the link I provided involves no usage of `sbt publish-local`. But actually, now that you've updated the question to be worded more clearly, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This person you are trying to give your project to: do you want them to be able to *build* your project themselves, or merely *run* it?

- If you want others to be able to build it: Add the library as an unmanaged dependency, as described [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html#unmanaged-dependencies). Put the library jar in the `lib` directory at the top level of your project, and check the jar into version control as part of your project.
- If you only want others to be able to run it, either:

  - Use the sbt-assembly plugin (https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) to create a single jar containing both your compiled code and the library's compiled code.
  - Or just leave it as two separate jars (yours and the library) and provide both jars to your users, perhaps along with a launch script.

Comment: yes, build. I have a project containing a few projects. However, I put a .jar in into the root `/lib` directory, removed it from `/project/Build.scala` and now it doesn't compile because it seems it can't find that .jar file.

Comment: Here's a transcript showing the `/lib` feature working: https://gist.github.com/SethTisue/d33c5a5e3fdd1e20b3b3 . Not sure why your project in particular would be different. Have you attempted to minimize the problem? Can you show us your build...?