# How to set up build with git-hosted external frontend project included?

Tags: angularjs, playframework, gruntjs, sbt

I have a Play 2.2 Application which strickly used only to implement REST API.

I have in an independent GIT repo a AngularJS application. This application uses Grunt and NodeJS to do the build.

The Result of the frontend application is an index.html + 1 js file and 1 css file.

Ideally I would like to invoke the Grunt build script from SBT which builds the angularjs app.

Is there a SBT plugin I can use to do this ?

What is the best approach I should use to do this the most simple way ?

At the moment I build it manually and copy the static resources into my PLAY's public folder.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never done it before, but a quick Google search gave me [sbt-grunt-plugin](https://github.com/guardian/sbt-grunt-plugin) whose the last commit was authored on Feb 20, 2013 :(

The plugin is a bit outdated, but is doing what I'd propose -- offers a command (could also be a task) that wraps grunt ([as the plugin above does](https://github.com/guardian/sbt-grunt-plugin/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/gu/SbtGruntPlugin.scala#L13)). You may also want to read the official documentation of sbt about [Commands](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Commands.html).

I would then declare a dependency on the angularjs/frontend project using `RootProject` for the `root` project with `frontend` (angularjs) and `backend` (Play Framework) submodules - see [How can sbt pull dependency artifacts from git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7550376/1305344):

```
lazy val frontend = RootProject(uri("git://..."))

lazy val backend = project ...
```

The `root` project is auto-created by sbt as described in [Default root project](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html#Default+root+project):

> If a project is not defined for the root directory in the build, sbt
>   creates a default one that aggregates all other projects in the build.

`frontend` would need to have `build.sbt` with the task created and it should work fairly well (it might be the only viable solution to not tie the projects too much and create unnecessary inter-dependencies).

Comment: Thanks, sbt-grunt-plugin looks good. Unfortunatelly the dependent project is not an SBT one / nor a Play one. Is it still worth using SBT RootProject to fetch it from Git ?

Comment: The idea is to `git clone` it at build time and execute `grunt` within. It's possible without converting the other project to an sbt-managed one. What command would you like to run in the frontend project?