# Integrate GitHub Libraries with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, github, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I would like to integrate GitHub Scala Libraries with IntelliJ IDEA. Please guide me how to integrate libraries with this jetbrain IDE.

Comment: What do you mean by 'integrate'? Do you want to use them in a project? You know that IntelliJ IDEA supports sbt build files, and sbt supports both regular libraries published to a Maven repository, or direct links to git repositories such as those hosted on GitHub?

Comment: yeah!!But, I am new to this IDE. I dont know how to include them in IntelliJ IDEA. can you give a link or procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you can come up with an sbt build file for your project that includes those libraries, all you have to do is *open* the project in IntelliJ IDEA - File > Open and select the directory in which the `build.sbt` file resides, then you will be offered to [import a project from the existing sbt build file](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2013/11/18/built-in-sbt-support-in-intellij-idea-13/).

Your minimal project directory will be

**project/build.properties**

```
sbt.version=0.13.9
```

**src/main/scala/mypackage**

Directory where your source code goes

**build.sbt**

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

// example library from Maven Central
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-swing_2.11" % "1.0.2"
```

Or, for [source repository that is not published](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550376/how-can-sbt-pull-dependency-artifacts-from-git):

**build.sbt**

```
lazy val root = Project("root", file("."))
  .dependsOn(libOnGitHub)
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
  )

// example project on GitHub
lazy val libOnGitHub = 
  ProjectRef(uri("git://github.com/user/repo.git#branch"), "project-name")
```

(This requires that the project is built by sbt, too)