# SBT Dependency to Git repository

Tags: git, github, build, sbt, build-dependencies

I want to use projects with no maven or sbt repo available and without doing the jar, only the Github is avalaible.
I found out it is possible via ([How can sbt pull dependency artifacts from git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550376/how-can-sbt-pull-dependency-artifacts-from-git))

In my build.sbt file I added :

```
lazy val datapackage = ProjectRef(uri("https://github.com/frictionlessdata/datapackage-java.git"),"datapackage-java")
lazy val tableschema = ProjectRef(uri("https://github.com/frictionlessdata/tableschema-java.git"),"tableschema-java")
```

And then

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
.dependsOn(datapackage)
.dependsOn(tableschema)

 // other libraries
 libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.6"
...
```

But I end up with unresolved dependency , it seems it's using some default repository and some pattern. As it seems it uses the line `scalaVersion := "2.12.2",name := """ODSD""",`

```
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: default#datapackage-java_2.12;0.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  :: default#tableschema-java_2.12;0.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      default:datapackage-java_2.12:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[warn]        +- odsd:odsd_2.12:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[warn]      default:tableschema-java_2.12:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[warn]        +- odsd:odsd_2.12:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

What would be the the issue?
And if it is not the best way to add the dependency what would be the best way? To this day I had luck and could always find the usual `libraryDependencies += ...` line...

Comment: Can you please clarify which `scalaVersion` are you expecting and why you don't see it? Where is the expected version set? In the downstream projects?

You may need to set the scala version in the root project.